# Rails join table over nested resources to access child_id from parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, join, nested-attributes

I think i may have programmed myself into a corner, but I will do my best tp explain the problem and see what can be done.  I have a map and marker model.  Map has_many Markers and Markers belongs to Map.  The map view has a form to create new markers, but I also need another form to edit individual markers which i would like to place within a marker infowindow.  Problem is I can't access individual marker_ids from the map controller.  So the way I see it is i either have to rewrite my marker views to take the place of the map views, or hopefully create a join table Map_Markers which contains map_id and marker_id.

If you would like to see any of my code just ask, but its so convoluted at this point id really just like to know if my plan is worth pursuing and the best way to approach it.

Sorry if this makes no sense, I am still working on fully understanding rails mvc.

Answer (score 0):

If a Marker can belong to many Maps and a Map can have many markers you need a join table MapMarkers. I would recommend using the [has_many :through approach](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) as opposed to the HABTM approach.

As much as possible, use Rails conventions when developing your app - it will save you a lot of headaches. Once you have implemented the new model structure, post some code and we can help you with the views and controllers.

You may want to first implement a simpler approach to the views to ensure you understand how to code the controllers and views. Once you have all your forms working individually, you can then refactor and move the forms into one view.